# Getting a specific portion of rotation in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, quaternions, euler-angles

I'm trying to implement gear physics using Unity, but I've encountered an issue. I've written the following code for one gear to follow another gear.

```cs
Quaternion targetRot = Quaternion.Inverse(Quaternion.Euler(targetGear.RelativeRotation.eulerAngles * ratio));
transform.rotation = _startRotation * targetRot;
```

If the ratio is not greater than 1, it works smoothly, but when the ratio is greater than 1, the object's right axis rotates by 180 degrees.For example.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WU5BP.gif)

When I halve the rotation as in the example, I want the larger gear to make a full rotation. How can I achieve this?

Comment: There is not enough information in question. What the property `targetGear.RelativeRotation` does, how it is calculated?

Comment: I calculate RelativeRotation as follows:

`public Quaternion RelativeRotation { get => Quaternion.Inverse(_startRotation) * transform.rotation; }`

Answer (score 1):

Why go through Euler angles (gimbal lock) at all?

Rather directly stick to the `Quaternion` instead.

Instead of the ratio multiplication you could instead use [`Quaternion.SlerpUnclamped`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.SlerpUnclamped.html)

```
// this interpolates between identity ("no change") and your relative rotation
// by doing this unclamped it basically equals multiplying by the ratio
var targetRot = Quaternion.Inverse(Quaternion.SlerpUnclamped(Quaternion.identity, targetGear.RelativeRotation, ratio));
transform.rotation = _startRotation * targetRot;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Using SlerpUnclamped to calculate half of the rotation worked correctly, but I couldn't achieve the desired result. If there is a 2-fold difference between the first gear and the second gear, when the first gear completes 360 degrees, the second gear jumps back to 0 degrees after 180 degrees. The reason I used Euler was to calculate beyond 180 degrees, but I couldn't manage it. I think there's a mistake in the logic I've set up.